# knitR latex code printed instead of the actual table

Tags: r, latex, knitr, xtable

I'm pretty knew to knitR and latex in general. My issue is that when I use xtable in a chunk, it does not produce a table, rather prints the latex code. When I try to use a variable as the table inline, it gives a summary of the table information.

```
<<r xtable, results="asis", cache=TRUE>>=
n <- 100
x <- rnorm(n)
y <- 2*x + rnorm(n)
out <- lm(y ~ x)
library(xtable)
tab <- xtable(summary(out)$coef, digits=c(0, 2, 2, 1, 2))
print(tab)
@
```

Causes the following to be in the pdf.

```
% latex table generated in R 3.2.1 by xtable 1.7 -4
% package
% Tue Jul 21 16:27:44 2015
\ begin { table }[ ht ]
\ centering
\ begin { tabular }{ rrrrr }
\ hline
& Estimate & Std . Error & t value & Pr ($ > $$ | $t$ |$ ) \\
\ hline
( Intercept ) & -0.14 & 0.10 & -1.5 & 0.14 \\
x & 1.89 & 0.10 & 19.3 & 0.00 \\
\ hline
\ end { tabular }
\ end { table }
```

and using 
    `$\Sexpr{tab}$`
gives 
    `c(−0.143521469746634, 1.88858473527988), c(0.0956794544572214, 0.097927637708342), c(−1.500023913815335)`

Comment: Please provide an reproducible example.  Using the chunk you posted and adding a document class plus `\begin`/``\end{document}` gives a PDF with a proper table.